# Listview Item highlight

Tags: java, android, android-listview

I have an android app where it has two list views in same screen. With one ListView i can get right result(I can highlight the pressed item). If i set the Adapter of the second ListView with setOnItemClick() method of first Listview, my first Listview's setSelected() method don't working. Can anyone help me?

And I also have *.xml files for `state_selected` tags. I want to highlight only one selected item and not multiple items.

Comment: can you put some code ?

Comment: share code, what you are trying.

Comment: @M.Zain i have edited my question

Comment: I still can't discover what you want to do... you have 2 lists, list1, and list2; what you want to do when you select item from list1, and what you want to do when you select item from list2

Comment: @M.Zain i want when i select/press any item of list1 change the background of that item.

Comment: @SerchatChasan please check the answer, and let me know if you want further help.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please share code, not images of code

Answer (score 0):

If you just need to change the color of the currently selected item in the ListView, just use change choiceMode attribute to "singleChoice", and select the color using listSelector attribute

```
<ListView
   android:layout_width="match_parent"
   android:layout_height="wrap_content"
   android:choiceMode="singleChoice"
   android:listSelector="@android:color/darker_gray"
/>
```

Comment: i have my custom layout for listview and i want to highlight more than one item. Thank you.

Comment: You want to highlight items on click and then dim them on another click like (custom item selection which usually done onLongClick of the first item?)